# Custom build failure callback

Tags: unity, build-process

I've been working on some custom build scripts, which will manipulate the references of certain MonoBehaviours.

I'm using `IPreprocessBuildWithReport` to do the manipulation, and I want to reset the references when the build completes. Even if the build fails, I want to do the operation, but I want to do some additional stuff if it fails. I'm also using `IPostprocessBuildWithReport` and `IProcessSceneWithReport` as well.

I've tried putting a Debug.Log in `OnProcessScene` and `OnPostProcessBuild`. I'm building without JAVA path defined, for Android, or without the Keystore password, which fails the build. The `IPreprocessBuildWithReport` correctly prints the Debug, but the others don't.

Is there any class or interface which has a callback for Build Failure which I can use? I've tried to get the summary from the `BuildReport` in `OnPreprocessBuild`, but the result is always returning `Unknown`.

Edit: I would also like to make the same changes if the Build was cancelled, rather than just if it was failing.

Platforms: Windows, Android

Unity 2019.3.7f1

Answer (score 1):

We started to use CompilationPipeline to detect the errors and trigger some custom actions. Here is the script template:

```
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using UnityEditor.Compilation;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Fiftytwo.BuildTools
{
    internal class BuildPreprocessor : IPreprocessBuildWithReport
    {
        private static object _compilationContext;
        private static int _compilationErrorCount;


        public int callbackOrder => 0;


        public void OnPreprocessBuild ( BuildReport report )
        {
            _compilationContext = null;
            _compilationErrorCount = 0;

            CompilationPipeline.compilationStarted += CompilationPipelineOnCompilationStarted;
            CompilationPipeline.assemblyCompilationFinished += CompilationPipelineOnAssemblyCompilationFinished;
            CompilationPipeline.compilationFinished += CompilationPipelineOnCompilationFinished;
        }

        private static void CompilationPipelineOnCompilationStarted ( object compilationContext )
        {
            _compilationContext = compilationContext;
            _compilationErrorCount = 0;
        }

        private static void CompilationPipelineOnAssemblyCompilationFinished ( string path, CompilerMessage[] messages )
        {
            for( int i = messages?.Length ?? 0; --i >= 0; )
            {
                if( messages[i].type == CompilerMessageType.Error )
                    ++_compilationErrorCount;
            }
        }

        private static void CompilationPipelineOnCompilationFinished ( object compilationContext )
        {
            if( compilationContext != _compilationContext )
                return;

            _compilationContext = null;

            CompilationPipeline.compilationStarted -= CompilationPipelineOnCompilationStarted;
            CompilationPipeline.assemblyCompilationFinished -= CompilationPipelineOnAssemblyCompilationFinished;
            CompilationPipeline.compilationFinished -= CompilationPipelineOnCompilationFinished;

            if( _compilationErrorCount > 0 )
            {
                Debug.LogError( $"Compilation finished with errors ({_compilationErrorCount})" );
                // Custom compilation failure processing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom build handler and invoke the unity default build process from there. For post-processing use `BuildHandler.OnBuildCleanup`, which is called when a build completes **or** fails.

````csharp
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class BuildHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action OnBuildStarted;
    public static event Action OnBuildCleanup;

    static BuildHandler()
    {
        BuildPlayerWindow.RegisterBuildPlayerHandler(Build);
    }

    private static void Build(BuildPlayerOptions buildOptions)
    {
        try
        {
            BuildStarted();

            //now start Unity's default building procedure
            BuildPlayerWindow.DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer(buildOptions);
        }
        catch (BuildPlayerWindow.BuildMethodException) { } //logged internally
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception log = ex.InnerException == null ? ex : ex.InnerException;
            Debug.LogException(log);
            Debug.LogErrorFormat("{0} in BuildHandler: '{1}'", log.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            BuildCleanup();
        }
    }

    private static void BuildStarted()
    {
        try
        {
            if (OnBuildStarted != null)
                OnBuildStarted.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("OnBuildStarted failed", ex);
        }
    }

    private static void BuildCleanup()
    {
        if (OnBuildCleanup != null)
        {
            foreach (Action cleanupBuild in OnBuildCleanup.GetInvocationList())
            {
                try
                {
                    cleanupBuild.Invoke();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Object context = cleanupBuild.Target as Object;
                    Debug.LogException(ex, context);
                    Debug.LogWarning("Caught exception while BuildHandler.OnBuildCleanup... Continuing");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````